# How to send file data as post parameter in BuzzBrowser post call

Tags: php, symfony, buzz

I am using [Buzz Browser](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php) for calling `POST` method. I am receiving a file from client at one of the `end point`.

```
$fileObj = $requestObject->files->get('image_data');
```

This is correct `fileObject`. I have verified this using `is_file()` method.

Now, I have to fire a `Buzz Browser` post event using this file as parameter.

```
$headers = array('Content-Type'=>'multipart/form-data'); 
$url = $genericHost . $api; //A valid URL
$params = array('image_data' => $fileObj);//fileObj obtained above
```

Posting this info using `buzzBrowser`

```
$browser->post($url, $headers, $params);
```

And receiving it as-

```
$fileObj = $this->get('request')->files->get('image_data');
```

But, the final `$fileObj` is `NULL`.

I tried to dump the `$this->get('request')->files`-

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#11 (1) {
["parameters":protected]=>
     array(0) {
    }
}
```

Means no file is there. What is wrong in my approach?

**Edit:1**

After debugging more, I found that file object is being sent as normal parameters:

```
["request"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["image_data"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/php6QLezs"
    }
  }
```

The header of the request is:

```
["headers"]=>
   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#13 (2) {
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["content-type"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(70) "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------1b3e33ff2ecb"
      }
      ["content-length"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "159"
       }
      ["host"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "host_name"
      }
      ["accept"]=>
        array(1) {
       [0]=>
       string(3) "*/*"
     }
     ["x-php-ob-level"]=>
      array(1) {
       [0]=>
       int(1)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by using `Buzz Browser's` **send** method.

```
use Buzz\Message\Form\FormRequest;
use Buzz\Message\Form\FormUpload; 

$request = new FormRequest();
$request->setField('image_data', new FormUpload($imageFilePath));
$request->setHeaders($headers);
$request->setMethod($method);
$request->setHost($genericHost);
$request->setResource($api);
$response= $this->browser->send($request, null);
```

It is still not solved using `post` of `Buzz Browser`